# Refresh exact URL by JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to refresh the exact URL after ajax success. I try the following way:

```
location.reload()
history.go(0)
location.href = location.href
location.href = location.pathname
location.replace(location.pathname)
```

But in fact, I have another problem, the URL is `https://example.com/electronic/?product_cat=mobile` but after using the mentioned code, the URL will change and the URL will be `https://example.com/electronic/`

is there any way to keep `?product_cat=mobile` after refreshing?

Comment: You must be missing something else. These functions (especially location.reload() ) does not remove the query string.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this will be

1. Get the current URL.
2. Redirect to it.

```
<script>
var current_url = window.location.href;
window.location.href = current_url;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @John, it refresh page for ever. and remove query.

Comment: No. You should add this code within your AJAX success code. It will reload the page after ajax completion only. Accept the Answer if it helps you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for keeping your doubts.
Could you cite an example of how to use it in wordpress?
If it is viable ..

tks

Comment: For Wordpress you have to create a custom plugin/short-code/script.